Create F5 load balancer instead of URL rewrite on IIS server but it cannot access to next page
We have operation to create F5 load balancer with new VIP instead of URL rewrite (server farm) on IIS server.
however we able to access by new VIP on log-in and main screen but when we click to other page, it will be occurred "Error internal 500" (Event viewer : ASP.net 4.0.30319.0 event id 1309)

Application language : C#
IIS .Net framework : 4.0

We tried to check configuration of Web.config and F5 load balancer rule
including disable server farm on IIS server but it's not resolve this problem.
Example different log from IIS server of VIP (F5) and IP of IIS server (URL rewrite)
Flow : 1.) Log-in  -> 2.) Main screen -> 3.) any page
URL rewrite
History log : 1.) -> 2.) -> 3.)
**F5 **
History log  : 1.) -> 3.) and error occurred "Access directly by specifying URL is prohibited"
Questions

We would like to know if we still remaining URL rewrite on Web server (once of destination server for F5 Load balancer), Is it possible occur from this point?
Event viewer : ASP.net 4.0.30319.0 event id 1309, Could you please kindly suggest what file's to checking?


The internal server error you are getting from application server. Its not F5 issue.
